# WPF Storyboard and update lable content issues

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard, wpf-controls

I have a story board that help me to perform a animation between 2 or more Canvas objects collection. In one of this canvas I have a Label that perform a simple count down update - who do not work.

Wen I truing to update THIS Label Content, after I perform a switch between 2 Canvas, the console give me that warning :

> System.Windows.Media.Animation Warning: 6 : Unable to perform action
>   because the specified Storyboard was never applied to this object for
>   interactive control.; Action='Stop';
>   Storyboard='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard';
>   Storyboard.HashCode='12309819';
>   Storyboard.Type='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard';
>   TargetElement='MyTest.MainWindow'; TargetElement.HashCode='17070976';
>   TargetElement.Type='MyTest.MainWindow'

The code example of my Switcher for Canvas object is :

```
 public Storyboard _storyboard = new Storyboard();
        const bool ToLeft = false;
        const bool ToRight = true;
        void ScreenSelector(FrameworkElement currentElement, FrameworkElement toNextElement, bool side)
        {
            if (_storyboard != null) _storyboard.Stop(this);

            var ticknessLeft = new Thickness(Width, 0, -Width, 0);
            var ticknessRight = new Thickness(-Width, 0, Width, 0);
            var ticknessClient = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);

            var timeSpanStarting = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
            var timeSpanStopping = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);

            var keyTimeStarting = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(timeSpanStarting);
            var keyTimeStopping = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(timeSpanStopping);

            toNextElement.Margin = side ? ticknessRight : ticknessLeft;
            toNextElement.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            var storyboardTemp = new Storyboard();

            var currentThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames = new ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames {BeginTime = timeSpanStarting};

            Storyboard.SetTargetName(currentThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames, currentElement.Name);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(currentThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames, new PropertyPath("(FrameworkElement.Margin)"));
            currentThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineThicknessKeyFrame(ticknessClient, keyTimeStarting));
            currentThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineThicknessKeyFrame(side ? ticknessLeft : ticknessRight, keyTimeStopping));

            storyboardTemp.Children.Add(currentThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames);

            var nextThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames = new ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames {BeginTime = timeSpanStarting};

            Storyboard.SetTargetName(nextThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames, toNextElement.Name);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(nextThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames, new PropertyPath("(FrameworkElement.Margin)"));
            nextThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineThicknessKeyFrame(side ? ticknessRight : ticknessLeft, keyTimeStarting));
            nextThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineThicknessKeyFrame(ticknessClient, keyTimeStopping));

            storyboardTemp.Children.Add(nextThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames);

            storyboardTemp.Completed += (EventHandler)delegate
                {
                currentElement.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                _storyboard = null;
            };

            _storyboard = storyboardTemp;
            BeginStoryboard(storyboardTemp);
        }
```

Now I have a MainWindow_KeyDown event where I check the button pressed :

```
    switch (e.Key)
    {
        case Key.A:
        {
            ScreenSelector(fr_GameGrid,Layer_1, ToLeft);
            GameEvents gm = new GameEvents();
            gm.OnTimer();
        }
        break;

        case Key.B:
        {
            ScreenSelector(Layer_1, fr_GameGrid, ToRight);
        }
        break;
```

I perform the "screen selector" - and start the simple count down timer. In GameEvent I have that simple code :

```
 public static void Countdown(int count, TimeSpan interval, Action<int> ts)
        {
            var dt = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = interval };
            dt.Tick += (_, a) =>
            {
                if (count-- == 0)
                    dt.Stop();
                else
                    ts(count);
            };
            ts(count);
            dt.Start();
        }
```

and the Using :

```
public void OnTimer()
        {
            /*
             * VALIDATE TIME
             * 
             * 
             * > OnAnswer
             */

            Countdown(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cur => lbTime.Content = cur.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

        }
```

Can anyone tell me where did I do wrong?, can't start the Label animation, and this is very strange - Because wen I update my Storyboard on line 6 -> this ( if (_storyboard != null) **_storyboard.Stop(this)**; ) to ( if (_storyboard != null) **_storyboard.Begin(this,true)**; ) the Warning disappears.

Comment: Your error just means that you can't stop a `Storyboard` on an object that it was never applied to.

Comment: Well I know about that - but why, wen I insert my countdown in the MainWindow Class that Update working perfectly ?